# Delete old site templates from solution gallery

Tags: sharepoint-online

What is the fastest way to empty the solution gallery on a SharePoint online site collection? They are all all unused (but active) site templates that are not needed anymore.
I hope that there's a better way than deactivate and remove one by one.
I tried:
Open the solution gallery with explorer view and delete, nothing happened, no error message
Open with designer, and delete, here came the message "deactivate first" up.